# Problem with code::blocks;Qt4;MingW;The procedure entry point.. could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore.dll:

Tags: qt, qt4, mingw, codeblocks

I am running Code::Blocks 10.05 with the MingW compiler package on a Win7-32 box.

I downloaded and installed the Qt libs for Windows/MingW (qt-win-opensource-4.7.3-mingw.exe) - installation went smoothly - BUT when it prompted me for the directory for MingW and I pointed it to Code::Blocks  installation directory, Qt installer told me my Qt package was for MingW 4.4 and I had 4.4.1 installed - 'installation may not work'. I installed anyhow, figuring there's no significant difference between 4.4 and 4.4.1 and the installation finished without error, all the Qt libs and tools are installed.

Afterwards, in Code::Blocks  I created a small test project using the Code::Blocks wizard - here is the code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    return app.exec();
}
```

The code built fine in the IDE - no errors or warnings, but when I ran it, I immediately received this error message, and the app exited with an error code:

> "The procedure entry point _ZI3qFlagLocationPKc could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library QtCore.dll"

Anybody know what's going on here? Is it because of the MingW version discrepancy I was warned on, or some other reason? How can I fix this? I want to use Qt Code::blocks, not Nokia QtCreator.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add %qtDir%\lib to your path before trying to copy all to system32. Reboot after adding, then all should run fine.

Also, you may need to rebuild qt libs with your compiler if all is still not working...

Comment: Will try that - thanks - didn't seem right that I'd have to dump everything into system32.

Comment: yes, also some features won't work in system32 without running them in administrator mode. If modifying path will fails, you may copy to your system32 dir only contents of qtdir\lib folder, where qtcore4.dll actually lives. Also, look your path for older qt installations, maybe wrong library used...

Comment: I added %qtDir%\lib and it didn't help, but after you mentioned to check for old installations, I also realized that I have pyQt installed, and the paths for pyQt were there before the Qt paths - I put %qtDir%\lib and the rest of the Qt paths first in the path and now it works fine. Tnx

Comment: I had a similar problem -- TortoiseHg was in my path, and that has its own version of the QT libs.  Thanks @Raiv for getting me to look in the right place!

Answer (score 1):

I used to have that errors, too. And having Qt libs in PATH doesn't seem to help, someone told me to put them into %WINDIR%\system32 and everything works fine after that...

Comment: So you think I should re install qt in system32? Will try that - tnx.

Comment: not all in my case, just QtCore and QtGUI. other dlls may reside in any directory in PATH, or along with the application. don't know about yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the variables: 
QTDIR - C:\Qt\4.7.3 (it's mine, you should write yours)

QMAKESPEC - win32-g++ (for MinGW)

PATH - C:\Qt\4.7.3\bin;C:\mingw\bin

Comment: Thanks - but no longer using code::blocks or QT - switched to codelite - http://www.codelite.org and  gtkmm - https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/index.html